# Sparklyr on Databricks - taking a mean of multiple columns rowwise on a sparklyr data frame with many NaN values

Tags: r, dplyr, databricks, sparklyr, azure-databricks

I'm trying to create min, max and mean columns for a sparklyr dataframe. I want to use only 5 columns from that large dataframe, rowwise in the calculation. There are many NaN values in the columns, which could be calculating things. In standard R the code used would be:

```
df_train$MinEncoding <- spark_apply(df_train,f=min ,columns=[,EncodingFeatures], 1, FUN=min,na.rm=TRUE)

df_train$MaxEncoding <- spark_apply(df_train[,EncodingFeatures], 1, FUN=max,na.rm=TRUE)

df_train$MeanEncoding <- spark_apply(df_train[,EncodingFeatures], 1, FUN=mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I have tried

```
df_train %>% spark_apply(function(df) {dplyr::mutate(df, MeanLicenceEncoding = mean(LicenceEncodingFeatures))})
```

However spark aborts the job. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

For variable columns, you can use [HIVE's](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) `greatest()` and `least()` with `dplyr` and `sparklyr` as follows:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
iris <- copy_to(sc, iris)

columns <- c("Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width")

transmute(iris,
          max = greatest(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(columns)),
          min = least(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(columns)),
          avg = sql(!! paste(paste("if(isnull(", columns, "), 0, ", columns, ")", collapse = " + "))) / !!length(columns))
```

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 3]
     max   min   avg
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   5.1   3.5  6.85
 2   4.9   3    6.4 
 3   4.7   3.2  6.3 
 4   4.6   3.1  6.15
 5   5     3.6  6.8 
 6   5.4   3.9  7.35
 7   4.6   3.4  6.3 
 8   5     3.4  6.7 
 9   4.4   2.9  5.85
10   4.9   3.1  6.45
# … with more rows
```

Comment: The code works with R data frames and also with Spark data frames. If you want to use Spark, make sure df_train is loaded using sparklyr using the spark_read_*() functions or copy_to().

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have an error returned : Error in min(EncodingMean, EncodingMean1, EncodingMean2, : Error in min(EncodingMean, EncodingMean1, EncodingMean2,  : 
  unused arguments (EncodingMean1, EncodingMean2, EncodingMean3, EncodingMean4)   

I thought this may be down to the NaN values however I have incorporated na.replace and the error is still returned. Any additional advice would be great

Comment: If you want the min/max/mean for all columns you could also run `sdf_describe(df_train, cols = c("name-of-column-1", "name-of-column-2", "name-of-column-3))`. Otherwise, since the code from this response works one column at a time, but you can explicitly compute more columns following a pattern like `min_col_1 = min(name_of_column_1, na.rm = TRUE), min_col_2 = min(name_of_column_2, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention the mean is across each row. By this I mean one mean should be computed from the Encoded1,Encoded2,Encoded3,Encoded4.

Comment: Ah, I see. Updated the answer to reflect avg, min, mean by row, not by column.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank alot. If you have any useful resources that help me develop my understanding of such code id love to hear them :)